# Changing image that opens when you click on dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made the changing picture that opens when I click on the dropdown. But when I copy this dropdown more than once, the changed image does not work.

```js
const image = document.querySelector('.item__img');
const checkbox = document.querySelectorAll('.imgOption');


function clickToChange() {
  let imgsrc = this.getAttribute("data-value");
  console.log(imgsrc);
  image.src = imgsrc;
}

checkbox.forEach(check => check.addEventListener('click', clickToChange));
```

```html
<div class="custom_select custom-select1">
  <a class="image_swap image">
    <img id="imageToSwap" class="item__img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </a>
  <div class="select">
    <div class="selectBtn" data-type="firstOption">test</div>
    <div class="selectDropdown mm-dropdown">
      <div class="option imgOption" data-type="firstOption" data-value="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
        test1
      </div>
      <div class="option imgOption" data-type="secondOption" data-value="https://via.placeholder.com/150x350">
        test2
      </div>
      <div class="option imgOption" data-type="thirdOption" data-value="https://via.placeholder.com/350x250">
        test3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="custom_select custom-select2">
  <a class="image_swap image">
    <img id="imageToSwap" class="item__img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </a>
  <div class="select">
    <div class="selectBtn" data-type="firstOption">test</div>
    <div class="selectDropdown mm-dropdown">
      <div class="option imgOption" data-type="firstOption" data-value="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
        test1
      </div>
      <div class="option imgOption" data-type="secondOption" data-value="https://via.placeholder.com/150x350">
        test2
      </div>
      <div class="option imgOption" data-type="thirdOption" data-value="https://via.placeholder.com/350x250">
        test3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your title and question to be clearer. As previously noted, there is no dropdown, and what is typically called a dropdown, the `select` element, does not take images.

Comment: I fixed your snippet. What is expected outcome from clicking?

Comment: You have ONE image you can change. If you want to repeat that, then you need to delegate and change the relative image using `this.closest(".custom_select").querySelector("img")`

Comment: There is no problem with changing the picture, I just want to use it more than once.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. use more than once. You mean you want to have TWO custom-select divs after each other?

Comment: I mean, for example, when there are 2 custom selects, both of them do not work separately. I want both pictures to change separately

Comment: I added 2 selects for you to understand what I'm saying. When the second select is pressed, the picture in the first select changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question tag with [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) so I shall give you jQuery solution.

Using `parents()`, which get the ancestors of each element in the current set of matched elements, find `img` element and give desire attribute `src`.

Example:

```js
const image = $('.item__img');
const checkbox = $('.imgOption');

checkbox.on("click", function(index, item) {
  let imgsrc = $(this).data("value");
  $(this).parents(':eq(2)').find('a > .item__img').attr("src", imgsrc);
})
```

```html
<div class="custom_select custom-select1">
  <a class="image_swap image">
    <img id="imageToSwap" class="item__img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </a>
  <div class="select">
    <div class="selectBtn" data-type="firstOption">test</div>
    <div class="selectDropdown mm-dropdown">
      <div class="option imgOption" data-type="firstOption" data-value="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
        test1
      </div>
      <div class="option imgOption" data-type="secondOption" data-value="https://via.placeholder.com/150x350">
        test2
      </div>
      <div class="option imgOption" data-type="thirdOption" data-value="https://via.placeholder.com/350x250">
        test3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="custom_select custom-select2">
  <a class="image_swap image">
    <img id="imageToSwap" class="item__img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </a>
  <div class="select">
    <div class="selectBtn" data-type="firstOption">test</div>
    <div class="selectDropdown mm-dropdown">
      <div class="option imgOption" data-type="firstOption" data-value="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
        test1
      </div>
      <div class="option imgOption" data-type="secondOption" data-value="https://via.placeholder.com/150x350">
        test2
      </div>
      <div class="option imgOption" data-type="thirdOption" data-value="https://via.placeholder.com/350x250">
        test3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```